# Adding picture to ArcMap PageLayout using ArcObjects in .NET?

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcobjects, symbology

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6 and I'm creating an Add-in to simultaneously add text (textelement populated from user input) and an image (company logo).  The issue i'm having is with the image.  I know there is a pictureelement but I have no idea how to work with a stdole.IPictureDisperse so I'm trying to see if I can use a PictureMarkerSymbol but no luck.

```
System.Uri myPictureUri = new System.Uri(picUrl);
PictureMarkerSymbol picm = myPictureUri as PictureMarkerSymbol;
graphContainer.AddElement(picm as IElement, 0);
```

Comment: What format is the image?

Comment: I have a bitmap, jpg, or png.  Whichever is easier, thanks

Comment: You don't want a PictureMarkerSymbol, you want an IPictureElement https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#ipictureelement.htm and then import using ImportPictureFromFile, I think you need to control location with IFrameElement https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFrameElement.htm which implements IPictureElement as PngPictureElement... my code isn't handy at the moment I'll get back to you on tuesday if you haven't sorted it yourself by then.

Comment: I forgot to ask, are you in data or layout view? I am assuming layout view (with scale bars, north arrows and legend objects) Have a read of https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#6c551e9f-ef5e-470a-9d89-01db5ddaa6b8.htm I think you can also add an IPictureElement to the data frame as a graphic via IGraphicsContainer http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#igraphicscontainer.htm

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I had looked at those links but I still had confusion so a code sample would help me tremendously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is some VBA that will add an image to the page layout, note this is a link to the image on the hard drive rather than embedding it into the map document. If you want it embedded simply adjust `IPictureElement5.SavePictureInDocument` Property.

```vb
Public Sub AddPictureToLayout()
    ' Get document
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument

    ' Load JPG image into Element
    Dim pPictureElement5 As IPictureElement5
    Set pPictureElement5 = New JpgPictureElement
    pPictureElement5.ImportPictureFromFile "C:\Scratch\myPicture.JPG"

    ' Create an envelope in PAGE units and assign to geometry
    Dim pEnvelope As IEnvelope
    Set pEnvelope = New Envelope
    pEnvelope.XMax = 12
    pEnvelope.XMin = 2
    pEnvelope.YMax = 10
    pEnvelope.YMin = 2
    Dim pGeometry As IGeometry
    Set pGeometry = pEnvelope

    ' Set picture to have envelope geometry, this places it on pagelayout
    Dim pElement As IElement
    Set pElement = pPictureElement5
    pElement.Geometry = pGeometry

    ' Set name property (useful)
    Dim pElementProp3 As IElementProperties3
    Set pElementProp3 = pElement
    pElementProp3.Name = "My Picture"

    ' Add picture to Layout and refresh
    Dim pPageLayout As IPageLayout
    Set pPageLayout = pMxDoc.PageLayout
    Dim pGraphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
    Set pGraphicsContainer = pPageLayout
    pGraphicsContainer.AddElement pElement, 0
    pGraphicsContainer.UpdateElement pElement
    pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Hornbydd, I will try converting this to c#.  Maybe one of the steps I was doing wrong (based on your code) is that I was assigning geometry of a point instead of polygon extent to the ipictureelement.  Would that cause an issue? Also you mentioned image path coming from hard drive, I was referencing the image on on a shared drive on the network. Could that cause an issue too?

Comment: The point geometry may have caused an error, until I set the geometry of the element the AddElement method threw a generic error. I would have thought the location of the image should not be an issue.

Comment: This worked, thanks Hornbydd and everyone that posted