# How to package an image with an Addin so it can be added to page layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, add-in, vb

This post shows the code I'm using to insert an image into the page layout. It works fine, but it's using a hard coded path.
[Adding picture to ArcMap PageLayout using ArcObjects in .NET?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281981/adding-picture-to-arcmap-pagelayout-using-arcobjects-in-net)

Currently my code looks for the image in the user's ArcGIS folder, or if not there at a shared network folder, or else it doesn't insert it.

```
    strPath1 = Environ("USERPROFILE") + "\Documents\ArcGIS\logo.bmp"
    strPath2 = "Z:\networkfolder\logo.bmp"
    If Exists(strPath1) Then
        picElement5.ImportPictureFromFile(strPath1)
    ElseIf Exists(strpath2) Then
        picElement5.ImportPictureFromFile(strPath2)
    Else
        Dim Result As DialogResult
        Dim Buttons As MessageBoxButtons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo
        Result = MessageBox.Show("image not found, not inserted", "title", Buttons)
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

What I would like to do is include the image in the Images folder of the AddIn. In the Config.esriaddinx file it allows images to be used from a subfolder, but picElement5.ImportPictureFromFile doesn't support relative paths.

Is there a different method to import an image into the page layout or a way to install them image into a standard folder that would work for all users. I need to distribute this addin to other users in the office.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.6, VB in Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the image in a folder and that is packaged as part of the AddIn then look at this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17423/finding-path-where-add-ins-are-installed-for-arcgis-desktop) it has some c# code to show you how to work out the folder location of where the AddIn is stored, it would then be a simple matter of building the path to the image and feeding it into `picElement5.ImportPictureFromFile()`.

Comment: At first I wasn't sure where to put that code, but it worked at the top of my module. Now to test it with other users. I think it will work.